# C reading lines from stdin

Tags: c, pipe

My goal is to read every line from a piped .txt file with the getline() function, but I somehow get a error every time I use this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int Chars;
  int size = 10;
  char *string;

  printf("Please enter a string: ");
  string = (char*) malloc(size);
  Chars = getline(&string, &size, stdin);

  if (Chars == -1)
  {
    puts("ERROR!");
  }
  else
  {
    puts("You entered the following string: ");
    puts(string);
    printf("\nCurrent size for string block: %d", Chars);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I always get the errorcode: [Error] Id retruned 1 exit status

Comment: getline is not a C standard function.

Comment: I thought that if you pipe a file.txt it just gets spit out into stdin?

Comment: Don't use `getline`, it's a non standard function, but use `fgets` instead. What is your platform (OS/compiler/IDE/...)?

Comment: Note:  1) I'd [expect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) `size` should be `size_t`. 2) "Current size for string block" is stored in `size`, not `Chars`.

Comment: I am using Dev-C++ right now for windows for C and C++

Comment: Enable all warnings and save time.  `getline(&string, &size, stdin);` should warn about mi-matched types.

Comment: C code. But may task is to read any example.txt files (that get piped into stdin)  that contain a random amount of numbers with the format: 40(space)3000(Newline)30 .... etc.

Comment: getline() sounded like the option to go with

Comment: @Unknown-max-byte You should ask yourself first: Is `getline()` available in Dev+C++ in the first place? If it isn't, `getline()` isn't an option to go with.

Comment: BTW if you are expecting lines to be length `7` plus newline and terminator I wouldn't use a buffer as small as `10` bytes. Be generous and use say `32`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Common `getline()` reallocates as needed.  Starting with 10, 32, or 0 makes scant difference.

Comment: Yeah thats what I read as well, but can I use fgets() for reading a piped file.txt. I thought that fgets() only reads the input you give after opening your program? And that it would wait for an input even after you pipe a file.txt in you program?

Comment: @Jabberwocky *Don't use `getline`, it's a non standard function*  [`getline()` is standardized](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) by just about the entire computing world other than Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced the linking error on *DevC++*, in which `getline()` seems to be missing even after forcing recent C revisions with **gcc** compiler options such as `-std=c11`.

So I've rewritten your code using `fgets()`:

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

It is for sure more portable than `getline` but has a few differences:

- It reads up to `size-1` characters if the newline is not encountered before this limit (it automatically appends the string terminator). So it doesn't manage buffer reallocation
- The resulting string contains the `'\n'` character, if found

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 32

int main( void )
{
  int len = 0;
  char *str;

  printf("Please enter a string: ");
  str = malloc(MAX_STR_SIZE);     /* (1) */

  while( 1 )
  {
    size_t newline_pos;
    
    fgets( str, MAX_STR_SIZE, stdin );
    /* (2) */

    if( len == 0) /* (3) */
    {
      puts("You entered the following string: ");
    }

    newline_pos = strcspn(str, "\n" );

    str[newline_pos] = '\0';
    len += strlen(str);   /* (4) */  
    fputs(str, stdout);

    if(newline_pos < MAX_STR_SIZE-1) /* (5) */
      break;
  }

  printf("\n\nCurrent size for string block: %d", len);

  free( str ); /* (6) */
  return 0;
}
```

So, basically, I just use `fgets` to read from `stdin`, iterating until the `'\n'` character is found. In order to understand is this condition is met, I use [strcspn()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn) function, and I use the same function to remove the newline from the resulting string.

A few notes/assumptions (check the corresponding number in code section):

1. Casting the result of `malloc` is required only if you are compiling with a C++ compiler. It can be omitted in C
2. Removed `fgets` error check: it returns NULL in case of error (no chars read before EOF is found. It won't happen reading from stdin)
3. Checking for `len==0` we make sure that the `"You entered the following string: "` is printed only once
4. The length of the string is calculated by summing the length of the strings read in every iteration
5. The `break` condition is met when the string contains `'\n'`. Otherwise `strcspn`'s return value will be `MAX_STR_SIZE`
6. Even if the OS will release all the dynamic memory used by the program, on return, it is a good habit always `free`ing it anyway

Comment: But what if I need to read a file that contains  \n ? Than it only reads until the \n am I right? Can I somehow loop it, but it begins reading after the \n ?

Comment: @Unknown-max-byte `fgets()` returns output line-by-line, so the `\n` is the last character read for every line (except for the last line of the file). If you actually need the `\n` char in your output you can simply skip the part in which I remove it.

Comment: So it just saves every line in str and reads the next line for str until the EOF?

Comment: @Unknown-max-byte Exactly. Unless the buffer you passed to it isn't big enough for the line: in fact it stops reading (1) at EOF, (2) at `\n`, (3) When `MAX_STR_SIZE-1` chars are read